# What do the contractors do when they remove a wall and the circuits in the wall need to stay there till later when an island is built?

Tags: electrical

This is both a logistical and technical (electrical) question

In the picture below I am paying a contractor to remove the wall marked with red and to install an LVL beam
1-fridge circuit.
2-MW circuit, same circuit as an outlet on wall marked with #3.

The cabinets on the removed wall will move to wall #3, the microwave currently plugged into #2 will use an outlet on wall #3 (same circuit).

Outlet #2 will be left behind because we will build an island there in 3-4 months.
Outlet #3 should be left in place because the fridge will also be left on the wall #4 for 3-4 months and then both the fridge and the outlet will move to wall number #3.

This work (removing the wall and installing the LVL beam) will require an inspector.

Question: what happens with the circuits #1 and #2 for these 3-4 months?
I want the inspector to come to see the LVL and the wall removal work and then if he is OK, I will have the contractor finish the drywall work required to nicely mask the LVL beam.

Having these said what does it need to be done with the outlets #1 and #2 so that the inspector can OK the work?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In many of the residential and commercial (office) remodels I've done, the lumber is cut away from the wiring, be it cables or conduit, and they're left behind. In some cases lumber is temporarily installed to protect circuits protruding from the floor.

We'd often have the electricians come and start their rough-in, at which time they might pull some of the obsolete circuit branches out of the way.

Otherwise, they wiring just lays around. Inspectors know that it's a work in progress and don't worry much about it unless there's a safety issue.

When in doubt, call and ask. They're just people doing a job and most are happy to discuss your project and offer advice.

Comment: I am ok with that but I am not sure how the inspector will react, that is my problem. Will he or she see validate and OK the LVL work if the outlets that were there before. I am OK with this on the floor under the island https://cdn2.tmbi.com/TFH/Step-By-Step/display/FH99SEP_OUTLET_10.JPG  That will be a dry island (no water there)

Comment: So call and ask. They're just people. :)

Comment: not working like that, you need the drawings (2K) and you need to submit the paperwork  and only then you get the guy's name. Not in the mood to spend more money from a stretched budget if I can't have the whole thing run as described. I would rather wait longer and do all that work then but then I will have to revisit the flooring work being done now

Comment: Surely you can call your inspection office and ask, in general terms, what they expect in this situation.

Comment: I was sent away for less a couple of good years ago when I wanted to know at least if I need an inspector for this. This is not my first rodeo with them. The answer was simple but the human robot I spoke with said no paperwork no talk ...they want to make money

Comment: Several years ago vs now - there may be new people to talk to.

Comment: @FreeMan  and if not?

Comment: @user253751 Then OP would have wasted a grand total of 5 minutes + the price of one phone call. Most people can comfortably afford that. (Or, given that we're well into the 21st century, they might also have e-mail addresses where OP could send a copy of this question and it would only take a minute.)

Comment: @TooTea but also hasn't solved their problem

Comment: As noted in a couple of answers here, @user253751, some internet guessing hasn't solved the OPs question in more than 2 days. That 5 minute phone call wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking us what the inspector will say or do and we don't know. The problem is that the inspection will be for the removal of the wall and installing the LVL beam. There's a good chance he/she won't OK the work until the outlets in that wall are reinstalled correctly at the final location. Remember too, that the inspector can check anything in the area for compliance, not just what he/she's there for. Your best bet would be to meet with the inspector and find out ahead of time what you need to do. Inspectors are a funny breed.

Comment: I am asking about a standard solution for this type of temp arrangement. I call it temp but for the inspector I can say it is permanent and then call an electrician to move it later. For now I am trying to see if there is a cheap solution to leave it in place somehow since I  am short of money (see the comment to the other answer )

Comment: If the wires go up, it’s legal to terminate them in a surface mounted jbox on the ceiling. If they go down, pull them into the crawl space/basement and terminate them in a jbox. The risk you run is that your new kitchen config won’t have enough outlets for code (spacing, # circuits, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of things you need to worry about if you are leaving cables temporarily hanging unprotected outside walls:

1. What will the inspector of a new structural beam think about them?
2. Ensuring the safety of the occupants during construction, if the room will be in continued use by them IE your family
3. Ensuring the safety of the construction workers
4. Gradually reconfiguring the cables into their final situation that can be approved by electrical code standards

IMO, the question you asked, #1, is the one LEAST amenable to an answer in this forum.   That inspector should not be concerned with temporary construction conditions, but that doesn't mean they won't be, especially if the conditions violate workplace safety rules or otherwise are so dangerous they can't be ignored.  And of course the inspector might go farther, even if they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a junction box in the ceiling somewhere near where these drops are, the wiring to these drops could be disconnected at the JB (tying all the rest of the wiring back together, of course, to keep power on elsewhere - *wait* you did take pics before you started messing with it, right??), and the drops to the affected outlets completely removed to prevent damage to the wiring and to prevent people from just smacking into them.

The wiring, boxes and their outlets/switches could be neatly tied up somewhere out of the way for 3-4 months so that people aren't banging into them and/or damaging the sheath housing the cable (assuming standard NM-B wiring).

If it's just a short-term wait, small temporary stud walls could be built to attach the cable & boxes to in order to be able to use the devices while you're waiting for the other work to be completed.

Comment: I am just planning, trying to see what the logistics will look like and what my budget will look like. I am doing the flooring (paying a contractor) on the floor adjacent to the wall that I want to remove so the idea is to have that floor done properly and for that I need to remove the wall NOW but I do not have the money to proceed with the entire kitchen reno (I can pay for moving the cabinets and removing the wall and installing the LVL beam but I can't pay them to build the island etc etc) so the plan is to see if I can have this temporary setup. 
There is no JB that I know or see.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to think about. You may not be aware but the National Electrical Code, US, requires a separate circuit for all fixed equipment, so a circuit must be used for any built-in oven or major appliance. Not knowing what microwave you have it would be best to run a separate circuit for it. Your refrigerator will also require a separate circuit. You will need a minimum of two 20-amp, GFCI-protected 120-volt dedicated circuits for these countertops and eating area outlets. The countertop outlets should not be more than four feet apart. The best thing you can do is talk to your inspector before starting to be sure you understand what is wanted. This can save you a lot of grief.

Sorry about the countertops. If you do not know the inspector, do as I do and go to the building department probably where they issue building permits and ask for help. At a minimum be sure the microwave is on a 20A circuit wired with a minimum of #12 AWG wire.

Comment: the problem that I have is that I do not know who the inspector will be. I think it is assigned by the city.
There is no countertops here. There will be an island there that will reuse that existing circuit (1)
(2) is a circuit by itself so the fridge is OK. The microwave is small capacity I might even make it disappear during the inspection (it is not built in, it sits on a shelf) so that is not an issue

Comment: Mostly correct, except: *requires a seperate circuit for all fixed equipment* AIUI, code always requires dedicated circuits for certain things (e.g., ovens) but for many other things they can share with receptacles *if* the fixed equipment uses < 1/2 the rated power of the circuit. For a 20A circuit, that would 10A or (more typically) 8A continuous. A typical dishwasher will use more than 1/2 a circuit and therefore need to be dedicated. At the other extreme, the ignition circuit for a gas cooktop (if hardwired and not plug-in) will use 1A or less and can definitely be shared with receptacles.

Comment: "requires a seperate circuit for all fixed equipment" - I'm pretty sure that is not true.